Polygon crossing the antimeridian and using intersect
I have this PostgreSQL/PostGIS SQL query which returns false:
select ST_Intersects(
               'SRID=4326;POLYGON((-66.885417 74.071038,-66.885417 18.7763,166.9999999 18.7763,166.9999999 74.071038,-66.885417 74.071038))'::GEOGRAPHY, --polygon
               'SRID=4326;POINT(-97.72 30.27)'::GEOGRAPHY --point within the polygon
       )
from test.abc
limit 1; -- returns false

I think the issue here is that the polygon crosses the antimeridian, but I was reading here that the geography type can handle the antimeridian fine, but according to the query that is not the truth.
Is our only hope here to split the polygon into 2 or shift the polygon via st_wrapx ?
EDIT: One thing I noticed is that when I change the point to ('SRID=4326;POINT(-97.72 33.27)')::geography then it works. It looks like the polygon is "bending" a little bit.
